# How do I get "awk" to work correctly within a "su -c" command?

Tags: linux, unix, jenkins

I'm running a script at the end of a Jenkins build to restart Tomcat.  Tomcat's shutdown.sh script is widely known not to work all in many instances and so my script is supposed to capture the PID of the Tomcat process and then attempt to manually shut it down.  Here is the command I'm using to capture the PID:

```
ps -ef | grep Bootstrap | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' > tomcat.pid
```

The output when manually runs retrieves the PID perfectly.  During the Jenkins build I have to switch users to run the command.  I'm using "su user -c 'commands'" like this:

```
su user -c "ps -ef | grep Bootstrap | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' > tomcat.pid"
```

Whenever I do this however, the "awk" portion doesn't seem to be working.  Instead of just retrieving the PID, it's capturing the entire process information.  Why is this?  How can I fix the command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `$2` is being processed by the original shell before being sent to the new user. Since the value of `$2` in the shell is blank, the `awk` command at the target shell essentially becomes `awk {print }`. To fix it, you just escape the `$2`:

```
su user -c "pushd $TOMCAT_HOME;ps -ef | grep Bootstrap | grep -v grep | awk '{print \$2}' > $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/tomcat.pid"
```

Note that you want the `$TOMCAT_HOME` to be processed by the original shell so that it's value is set properly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the pushd command as you can replace the awk command with:

```
cut -d\  -f2
```

Note: two 2 spaces between `-d\` and `-f2`

Comment: The pushd isn't necessary for this snippet.  There's more to the command that wasn't shown and so it appears out of context, but is needed for the few commands that follow. Sorry for that.